# Notice: Undefined variable: consulta_mysql in

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
```

include 'connection.php';

```
//dame tareas para el combobox
function dameproducto(){
    $consulta_mysql="
        SELECT 
            tbproducto.nvchproducto,
            tbproducto.intidproducto,
            tbproducto.nvchcantidad
        from 
        tbproducto
    ";
    $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysqli_query($consulta_mysql);
    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)){
        echo "
              <option style='' value='".$registro['intidproducto']."'>
                PROD000".$registro['intidproducto']." - ".$registro['nvchproducto']." - distribuidor: ".$registro['nvchcantidad']."".$registro['inidproducto']."
              </option>
        ";
    }
}

function damelista(){
    $consulta_mysqli="
        SELECT
          tbstock.intidstock,
          tbproducto.intidproducto,
          tbproducto.nvchproducto,
          tbproducto.nvchdescripcion,
          tbproducto.nvchcantidad AS proveedor,
          tbstock.nvchcantidad
        FROM
          tbproducto
        INNER JOIN
          tbstock ON tbstock.inidproducto = tbproducto.intidproducto
    ";
```

> En esta parte es donde me marca el error

```
    $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysqli_query($consulta_mysql);
    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)){

        if($registro['nvchcantidad'] < 0){
            $tiporeg = "<span class='label label-danger'>Pedido Producto</span>";
        }else
        if($registro['nvchcantidad'] >= 0){
            $tiporeg = "<span class='label label-success'>Ingreso Producto</span>";
        }

        $tipo = 'UND.';
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>REG000".$registro['intidstock']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['nvchproducto']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['nvchdescripcion']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['proveedor']."</td>
                <td>".abs($registro['nvchcantidad']).' '.$tipo."</td>
                <td>".$tiporeg."</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='?action=editar&intidstock=".$registro['intidstock']."' style='background-color: green; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;color: white; font-size:12px' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Editar Pedido'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>
                    <a href='?action=eliminar&intidstock=".$registro['intidstock']."' style='background-color: red; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;color: white; font-size:12px' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Eliminar Pedido'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}

function tableprod(){
    $consulta_mysqli="
        SELECT
          tbstock.intidstock,
          tbproducto.intidproducto,
          tbproducto.nvchproducto,
          tbproducto.nvchdescripcion,
          tbproducto.nvchcantidad AS proveedor,
          sum(tbstock.nvchcantidad) as stocktotal
        FROM
          tbproducto
        INNER JOIN
          tbstock ON tbstock.inidproducto = tbproducto.intidproducto
          group by tbproducto.intidproducto
    ";
    $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysqli_query($con,$consulta_mysql);
    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)){

    //Estado del producto
    if($registro['stocktotal']<0){
        $cantproducto = '0';
        $nstock = '<span class="label label-danger"><b>'.abs($registro['stocktotal']).' UND.</b> Entregas Pendientes</span> ';

    }else
    if($registro['stocktotal']>=0 && $registro['stocktotal']<=12 ){
        $cantproducto = abs($registro['stocktotal']);
        $nstock = '<span class="label label-warning">Realizar Pedido</span>';
    }else
    if($registro['stocktotal']>=12){
        $cantproducto = abs($registro['stocktotal']);
        $nstock = '<span class="label label-success">STOCK suficiente</span>';
    }

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td> REG000".$registro['intidstock']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['nvchproducto']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['nvchdescripcion']."</td>
                <td>".$registro['proveedor']."</td>
                <td>".$cantproducto." UND.</td>
                <td>".$nstock."</td>
                <!--td>
                    <a href='?action=eliminar&intidstock=".$registro['intidstock']."' style='background-color: red; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;color: white; font-size:12px' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Eliminar Ingreso'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                </td-->
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: ¿En qué parte asignas valor a `$consulta_mysql`? Recuerda que cuando usas la librería `mysqli`, el primer parámetro en `mysqli_query` es el objeto de conexión, y luego la consulta.

Comment: @Seba está en el título, creo.

Comment: Mi error disculpen es que estoy acostumbrado a mirar el error en la descripción.

Comment: El error indica que la **variable `$consulta_mysql` no existe**. Además, como dice @quinqui, `mysqli_query` necesita también recibir el  objeto conexión en parámetro para trabajar. Sería bueno que muestres la parte del código donde creas dicha variable, y que indiques cómo se llama tu objeto de conexión.

Comment: El código no está completo para tratar de replicar el error.

Comment: ya agregue todo el código me podrían ayudar ? 
No se cual sea el error

Answer (score -4, accepted):

La función mysql_query() requiere dos parámetros obligatorios que son la conexión de la base de datos y la consulta o query.

Ejemplo:

```
$con = "tu conexion";

mysqli_query($con, $consulta_mysql);
```

Espero te haya servido.
Saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que la conexión se llama `$con`?

Comment: Si eres programador sabrías porque puse esa variable de ejemplo.. es solo una guía para que se de cuenta que le hace falta ese valor en el código.

Comment: @RodneyGuillén las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor edita tu publicación para añadir una pequeña descripción de qué hace ese código y cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](/help/formatting) para más información y consejos. Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente @RodneyGuillén muchas gracias. me faltaba pasar la variable de mi conexión.

Answer (score -1):

te dejo un ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo , podrias tambien revisar como estas pasando la conexion a la consulta:

```
<?php
/* mi conexion*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* VERIFICAR CONEXION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conxion fallida : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM productos ORDER by id ";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo $row['precio'];
}

/* liberando el result */
$result->close();

/* cerrando mi conexion */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```